# How to open terminal on Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce4-terminal

I have Xubuntu running my mouse does not working.

I was trying to open terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

It was not worked and googled I found that opening terminal shortcut will not work. Now I want to open terminal through Application but I don't know KB shortcut for opening Applications. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: From 13.10 Ctrl+Alt+T has been added as a kbd shortcut for the Terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default shortcut for Terminal in XUbuntu is <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

edit:

From what I've just seen, it is default on all machine I tested installed with xubuntu live CD 12.04 but it doesn't work on 1 machine I installed with ubuntu in the past (2008 or 2009) and migrated to xfce installing `xubuntu-desktop` last year.

Comment: What you are accessing here is the default terminal program, if there is one. I have found on some installations this doesn't get populated, and the above will not get you a result. Therefore, adding a shortcut to xfce4-terminal is a better answer. It may also be necessary to install xfce4-terminal first, if it is not already present, as well.

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to `Applications Menu (Start menu in Windows) -> Settings -> Settings Manager`
2. Find `Keyboard` and click it.
3. Go to "Applications shortcuts" and click <kbd>Add</kbd> button, near the bottom of the window.
4. Don't worry about anything else, just type this in the "Command" field and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.
   Enter: `xfce4-terminal`
5. As soon as the "Command" dialog opens, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> (or any other keyboard shortcut of your preference).

That's it. Close the keyboard window and you're done.

Comment: OP says the mouse is non-functional. The answer seems to require use of the mouse.

Comment: He can navigate using the kbd as well. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type `xfce4-terminal` or `xterm` to run the terminal.

To get the application menu with the keyboard press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

If that doesn't work you can use the Linux virtual consoles. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to<kbd>F6</kbd>. This gives you a text only session. To get back to the graphical login press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: I suspect this answer is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some useful stuff:

I installed the Xfce desktop from Linux Mint 17.2. The xfce4-terminal is not installed. I could install it but I prefer the gnome terminal. So, for anyone in similar situations, you should follow Frantique's instructions replacing "xfce4-terminal" command with "gnome-terminal".

Peace.

Comment: Answers are called answers for a reason: they have to provide a solution to the question.

Comment: I tried add comments to other answers but I can't.

Comment: And that's why you actually answer questions so that you can gain the reputation to comment. The Q&A system is made a certain way. Don't just ignore it.

Comment: Look, I'm new to Linux. I was looking for a solution like the one given by Frantique and I realised that the command gnome-terminal could be used in my case. At any forum people try to answer adjacent questions. What's the big deal?

Comment: Take a look at [the Help page](http://askubuntu.com/help)