# Can't set "Alt+Ctrl+T" to launch terminal in xfce4

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I followed normal steps to assign <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window. (Menu → *Settings Manager* → *Keyboard* → *Application Shortcuts* → Add and follow steps) but it just doesn't seem to work. I was following this: [How to open terminal on Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217079/how-to-open-terminal-on-xubuntu) and some other sources.

Why isn't it working? How do I make it work?

Comment: Did you try another key combination? Did you try this command `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator` for the shortcut? What is your Ubuntu version? Is it an updated system from 13.04 to 14.04 or something else? ALT+CTRL+T works well on my Xubuntu 14.04 to open a terminal.

Comment: weird! Why not work with me!?! I'm with a clean 14.04 Ubuntu + ubuntustudio-desktop (which is xfce). ...Tried `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator` now but still no good :( maybe I'm doing something wrong @Tuknutx

Comment: Did you have a `.Xmodmap` file in your home folder? Perhaps something of this will help http://askubuntu.com/questions/375709/unable-to-add-edit-keyboard-shortcuts-in-xfce4 or  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1292290 ?

Comment: no I don't have that! (the `.Xmodmap`) If this is what I need, how do I get it? ...I checked the links but both are not dealing with my problem.

Comment: no you need no .Xmodmap.

Comment: `Super` + `T` might also work by default.

Answer (score 22):

I'd like to suggest the following steps:

1. go to 'Start' at the top left corner, and open Settings Manager

   or

   open Terminal and type `xfce4-settings-manager`
2. open Keyboard
3. open Application Shortcuts Tab
4. click Add button (with greed-icon) below
5. type xfce4-terminal
6. trigger the shortcut, which is in this (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)

Good luck!

Comment: OP already did that

Comment: This won't work if the Xubuntu environment was not installed completely.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for the command `gnome-terminal`, using XFCE and TigerVNC. Go to the XFCE settings or run `xfce4-settings-manager`, then `Keyboard`, `Application Shortcuts`. Press `Add` and use `gnome-terminal` as the command you want to trigger and finally the shortcut.

Comment: This works because you have either gnome, unit or mate DE installed on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Run xfce4-settings-manager
Go to Window -> shortcuts -> add -> put the following as a command to run:
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator
Then, select the key combination

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest double-checking your command in the shortcut list. I know I still have a tendency to leave the 4 out of xfce4-terminal sometimes.

Comment: I tried many many commands and none worked till now :(

Answer (score 0):

The most common and overlooked reason: see if any other program has acquired the same shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

- press `alt+f2`
- search `xfce4-keyboard-settings`
- in keyboard>Application shortcuts>add
- in shortcut command>Command>type `xfce4-terminal`>ok
- the next window waits for keystrokes> press `ctrl+alt+T` or your proffered combination close

XFCE 4.14